# How to select a result from a result that return by a SQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I'm using SQL and PHP to pull information from my database and it returned a list of users that met the criteria. And I need to redirect to another page using the selected amount from the picture below. How can I grab this amount to another page?
For example, when I click the first select, I can go to the other page that showing $24, and Rubinsztein Abdel, 182 Crownhardt Lane...

[image]

```
    <!--loader end-->
  <!-- Main  -->
  <div id="main">
    <!-- wrapper -->
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div class="content">
        <!-- Map -->
        <div class="map-container column-map right-pos-map">
          <div id="map-main"></div>
          <ul class="mapnavigation"></ul>
          <div class="scrollContorl mapnavbtn" title="Enable Scrolling"><span><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Map end -->
        <!--col-list-wrap -->
        <div class="col-list-wrap left-list">
          <!-- list-main-wrap-->
          <div class="list-main-wrap fl-wrap card-listing">
              <!-- listing-item -->
              <?php
              ini_set('display_errors', 1);
              ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
              error_reporting(E_ALL);

              $severname = "localhost";
              $username = "root";
              $password = "";
              $dbname = "dbn";

                //$conn = mysqli_connect('xx', 'xx', 'xx','xx');
              $conn = mysqli_connect('dxx', 'xx', 'xx','xx');
              //check connection
              if (mysqli_connect_errno())
              {echo nl2br("Failed to connect to MySQL: ". mysqli_connect_error() . "\n"); }
              else
              { echo nl2br("");}

              $city = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['city']);
              $date1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['date1']);
              $date2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['date2']);
              $pet = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pet']);

              //var_dump($date2);

              $sql = "SELECT CONCAT(s.lname, ' ', s.fname) AS fullName, s.ratings, s.rate, s.phone, s.address FROM Pet_Sitter AS s WHERE s.citystate='".$city."' AND s.pet_type='".$pet."' "
                  ;
              //echo $sql."<br/>";
              $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
              if (!$result) {
                  printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));
                  exit();
              }

              if ($result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
                {
                // Return the number of rows in result set
                $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
                printf("");
                }

              //var_dump($result);

              $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
              ?> <div class="container"> <?php


              if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                //var_dump($row);
                // echo "<tr><td>" . $row['fullName'] . " </td><td>" . $row['ratings'] . " </td><td>" . $row['rate'] . " </td></tr>";
                // echo '<div class="listing-item">';
                echo '<div class="listing-item">';
                echo '<article class="geodir-category-listing fl-wrap">';
                echo '<div class="geodir-category-img">';
                echo '<img src="../images/all/1.jpg" alt="">';
                echo '<div class="overlay"></div>';
                echo '<div class="list-post-counter"><span>' . $row['rate'] . '</span></div>';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '<div class="geodir-category-content fl-wrap">';
                echo '<a class="listing-geodir-category" href="../index.html">Pet sitting</a>';
                echo '<h3><a href="../index.html">' . $row['fullName'] . '</a></h3>';
                echo '<p>PET-SITTER INFORMATION</p>';
                echo '<div class="geodir-category-options fl-wrap">';
                echo '<span>' . 'Reviews ' . $row['ratings'] .'</span>';
                echo '<div class="geodir-category-location">'. $row['address'] . " · " . $row['phone'] .
                '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '</article>';
                echo '</div>';
              }?>
              <?php



              } else {
                  echo "0 results";
                }
                  mysqli_close($conn);

              ?>

            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: You can make the `a href` go to a php page and pass the parameters. Example:
`echo '<h3><a href="../index.php?id=' . $row['listing_id'] . '">' . $row['fullName'] . '</a></h3>';`

Comment: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do it is to create one page (the one you wanna go if you click on your items) and use GET on URL to get the page id;

On your actual page you will use a link like :

```
<a href="new-page.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"
```

Here the `?id=` on URL is a parameter, that you can get on the other page :

```
$pageId = $_GET['id'];
```

Then, you just have to make a SQL request

```
SELECT * FROM Pet_Sitter WHERE id=$pageId
```

(better to use prepare and execute for this request as the value of `$pageId` can be change by everybody by changing the URL).

So every time you click on a link, the page will display the matching informations.

Also you should closed `<?php` when you are writing `HTML` instead of using a lot of `echo`.

Comment: Could you please let me know where should I insert the <a href="new-page.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" in my original page

Comment: It just have to be in your While loop, but you can insert it where you want, I guess you want it in the select button you have